# Why is my image not uploading?

Tags: image, magento, configuration, upload, backend

I'm trying to add a working image upload field to my new Magento configuration section, but it isn't working. Whenever I "upload" a file (pick a file, then save the config), the backend model function `_beforeSave()` (which I, possibly by error, located in `app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Model/System/Config/Backend/File.php`) isn't being called and the file isn't uploaded either. Any thoughts?

I'm using a module called Page in my own namespace in the local code pool. Is this causing problems? I don't need to call it that, and why it's called "Page" is a long story.

System.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config>
  <sections>
    <newtheme module="page" translate="label">
      <label>Newtheme</label>
      <sort_order>200</sort_order>
      <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
      <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
      <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
      <tab>general</tab>
      <groups>
        <homepage translate="label">
          <label>Home Page</label>
          <comment>Some comment about my group</comment>
          <sort_order>10</sort_order>
          <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
          <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
          <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
          <fields>
            <banner_image translate="label tooltip comment">
              <label>Image upload</label>
              <comment>This is an image field</comment>
              <tooltip>Image tooltip!</tooltip>
              <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
              <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
              <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
              <sort_order>200</sort_order>
              <frontend_type>image</frontend_type>
              <backend_model>adminhtml/system_config_backend_image</backend_model>
              <upload_dir config="system/filesystem/media" scope_info="1">newtheme/homepage</upload_dir>
              <base_url type="media" scope_info="1">newtheme/homepage</base_url>
            </banner_image>
          </fields>
        </homepage>
      </groups>
    </newtheme>
  </sections>
</config>
```

I also have an adminhtml.xml, but guess it works, because I can open the section just fine.

Got the headers using Firefox' Live HTTP Headers (I use a Mac) for the POST to the following url: http://example.com/index.php/admin/system_config/save/section/newtheme/key/84670cdcd055b925312eb3ecf0cb98e1/

```
POST /index.php/admin/system_config/save/section/newtheme/key/84670cdcd055b925312eb3ecf0cb98e1/ HTTP/1.1
Host: example.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.7; rv:7.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/7.0.1
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: nl,en-us;q=0.7,en;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
Connection: keep-alive
Referer: http://example.com/index.php/admin/system_config/edit/section/newtheme/key/eba46a991cc50c762cdac658da954c8a/
Cookie: adminhtml=23f1b26aa83ff7208b47b350794616f9
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=---------------------------9849436581144108930470211272
Content-Length: 97451
-----------------------------9849436581144108930470211272
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="form_key"

2vTBh14zpv3FCEAV
-----------------------------9849436581144108930470211272
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="config_state[newtheme_homepage]"

1
-----------------------------9849436581144108930470211272
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="groups[homepage][fields][mycustom_field][value]"

jkflsjfgkld
-----------------------------9849436581144108930470211272
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="groups[homepage][fields][image_field][value]"; filename="sub_banner_3.png"
Content-Type: image/png

PNG


HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Date: Thu, 02 Feb 2012 07:57:07 GMT
Server: Apache/2
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.2.17
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Pragma: no-cache
Set-Cookie: adminhtml=23f1b26aa83ff7208b47b350794616f9; expires=Sat, 04-Feb-2012 07:57:08 GMT; path=/; domain=example.com; httponly
Location: http://example.com/index.php/admin/system_config/edit/section/newtheme/key/eba46a991cc50c762cdac658da954c8a/
Vary: Accept-Encoding,User-Agent
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Length: 20
Keep-Alive: timeout=1, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

I guess the file is being sent alright. So why isn't is saved? Is it the backend model that isn't called the right way?

Comment: fire up fiddler and see if it gets posted properly and see what your script returns for upload

Comment: added headers to my question. I have a Mac, so using Fiddler is kinda hard. Not impossible, though, in case you think I really need it.

Comment: other tools won't show you the flash headers or responses. fire up windows in virtual machine or use http://www.charlesproxy.com/ for os-x . I don't think you really need this but it is a essential in debugging flash uploads or how else you would find out easily what your script responds to flash :)

Comment: It doesn't use flash, other image fields in the magenta admin (like the "Base Image Watermark" to be found under "Design" on which I've based this one) don't either. I'm not sure we're on the same page. I don't mean the image upload section of the product pages (which do use flash), I'm talking about the image uploads in the configuration sections.

Comment: in this case debug the backend model

Comment: how? I've put `Mage::log`s in the `_beforeSave()` method, but it's not firing.

Comment: if you have Firefox, you can use `Live Http Headers` addon.

Comment: Thank you, but as you can see, I already used the Live HTTP Headers add-on for firefox 4 hours ago.

Comment: @AntonS Sorry, didn't see your comment at first. I'm not sure, how would you debug PHP? Is it anything like traditional application debugging (like GDB when programming in C for instance)? I'm running Debian, are there packages I can install?

Comment: OMG just found out XDebug has remote debugging functionality. Never knew. Thanks for the heads up!

Answer (score 0):

Hello Please follow this
Check if helpers is included in config.xml else add below helpers block

```
<helpers><newtheme><class>NAMESPACE_Newtheme_Helper</class></newtheme></helpers>
```

And Also check if the module name you are using is case sensitive everywhere as in linux there is difference in newtheme and Newtheme
Also check if the folder is created in media newtheme/homepage
Clear the cache and session and then check, let me know if it works after checking above things

Comment: Thank you for your contribution, I am currently very busy with school stuff, but I will get back to you with the results, promise!